# Notation for free variables in a wf $\mathscr B$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So I am having some confusion about the notation that is used in "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson for indicating that some of the variables are free in a wf $\mathscr B$.[Below exercise 2.5]

> We shall often indicate that some of the variables $x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}$ are free variables in a wf $\mathscr B$ by writing $\mathscr B$ as $\mathscr B(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k})$ .This does not mean that $\mathscr B$ contains these variables as free variables , nor does it mean that $\mathscr B$ does not contain other free variables.

In order for a variable to be a free variable in $\mathscr B$ , it has to have an free occurrence in the wf $\mathscr B$ atleast once.So if a variable $x$ doesn't exist in a wf $\mathscr B$ , then it is not a free variable in $\mathscr B$.
But , the above passage allows us to indicate these "non existent variables" as free variables in $\mathscr B$ by using the notation $\mathscr B(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k})$. Is this right to do?

There is another confusion of mine regarding non-Existent variables. Lets say $y$ is a variable that doesn't exist in $\mathscr B$ .Then because $\mathscr B$ doesn't have $y$ as a variable , so we can write $\mathscr B \equiv \forall y\mathscr B$ according to this passage.

> Notice that $\mathscr B$ need  not contain the variable $y$. In that case, we understand (($\forall y)\mathscr B$) to mean the same thing as $\mathscr B$

In this case , $y$ is bound in $\forall y \mathscr B$ .And because $\mathscr B \equiv \forall y\mathscr B$ , we can say that $y$ is bound in $\mathscr B$.Is this faulty?

Comment: It is only a convention. See also [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=uegOCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA66)

Comment: If it is disturbing for you, you can imagine $B':=B\land(x_1=x_1\land x_2=x_2\land\dots)$.

Comment: I guess the question is := Are non existing variables in $\mathscr B$ considered **free** variables in $\mathscr B$ ?

Comment: Again, the issue is the difference between a formula of the language: $A_1^2(x_1,x_2)$ and a schematic expression of the meta-language. Having said that, see page 49: "An occurrence of a variable $x$ is said to be *bound* in a wf $\mathscr B$ if either it is the occurrence of $x$ in a quantifier “$(∀x)$” in $\mathscr B$ or it lies within the scope of a quantifier “$(∀x)$” in $\mathscr B$. Otherwise, the occurrence is said to be *free* in $\mathscr B$." Thus, if var $x_1$ does **not** occur in the formula it is neither free nor bound.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that is exactly where my confusion began . According to the introductory definition of free and bound variables , non-Existent variables are neither free or bound. But then according to the convention , non Existent variables are thought of as free variables too.

Comment: One is the "notation" used in the meta-language suited for human readibility (abbreviations, etc.) one is the formal specification of the syntax. $A_1^1(x_1)$ is a formula with an occurrence of $x_1$ free. $\forall x_1A_1^2(x_1,x_2)$ is a formula with an occurrence of $x_2$ free and two occurrences of $x_1$ both bound.

Comment: $\forall x_2 A_1^1(x_1)$ is a formula with an occurrence of $x_2$ that is bound and one occurrence of $x_1$ that is free. We can prove that the formula is equivalent to formula $A_1^1(x_1)$ (which is a different formula) where we have only one occurrence of $x_1$ free.

Comment: Mendelson's convention is rather loose but suggestive: $\mathcal{B}(x_{i_1}, \ldots, x_{i_k})$ is just an indicator that some of the $x_{i_j}$ may appear free  in $\mathcal{B}$. This allows him to write $\mathcal{B}(t_1, \ldots, t_k)$ for the result of substituting a list of terms $t_j$ for the $x_{i_j}$, which makes it reasonably clear what is substituted for what, but doesn't imply that all the $x_{ij}$ actually appear free. (So he can describe substitution of $1$ for $x$ and $2$ for $y$ in $x = x \land z = 3$, even though $y$ doesn't appear free in the formula, while $z$ does.)

Comment: @RobArthan that answers my first confusion perfectly . What are your thoughts about the second confusion I have?

Comment: If $y$ is not free in $\mathcal{B}$, then $\forall y \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ have the same meaning (they are logically equivalent) but they are not syntactically identical. You can write $\mathcal{B} \equiv \forall y \mathcal{B}$ (if you are using $\equiv$ for logical equivalence, which I don't think Mendelson does), but it doesn't mean that the two formulas have the same syntactic properties and whether or not a variables occurs bound in a formula is a syntactic property.

Comment: @RobArthan Lesson Learned: Logical Equivalence doesn't imply Syntactic Equivalence.